# How likely will I be able to get a job in game design with a masters in computer programming?

Tags: game-design, software-engineering, career, jobs

I'm currently attending college and am almost finish with my Bachelors in Computers science.I plan on getting my masters in computer programming in hopes that it will help me get into game design. If not I at least will have a fallback plan in any other IT related field. I'm just curious as to how likely it is to happen for me.

Comment: If you want to get into games with a degree, why wouldn't you just go with Digipen?

Comment: 50% - you either get a job, or you don't get a job.

Comment: Get yourself experience in building games by participating in building an extensive mod for an existing game.

Comment: @MatthewRock Unfortunately that's not how probability works...

Comment: @Moyli I joke. But this is imho the only sensible answer in this case. The answer to "How likely will I be able to get a job X with a degree" is "depends on your skills"(unfortunately this isn't always true, but I think that this is the case where it is); but even then you might get (un)lucky.

Comment: It also depends on where you live..

Comment: So do you want to be a game designer or do you want to be a programmer?  That isn't the same job unless you're working for a very small company and basically programming your own game.

Comment: "It depends on a countless number of factors." is the single most appropriate answer to this too-broad question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should notice that game design is nothing that is necessarily related to programming. It also applies to board games, card games and every type of game, computer games being one of these. It's a different field and being a good programmer doesn't mean you're a good game designer. However being a programmer already can help you becoming a good game designer because as such you have to have knowledge about what's possible in game development.

I'm currently on the same path working towards my masters degree in media informatics and thinking about how to get into the games industry. Unless you want to be an indie you don't have to master both programming and game design.

Either way start making games with one of the popular engines out there. You will have to be the programmer and the game designer at the same time. Make a lot of games. Most of them will suck but you'll become better and better. Ragarding your question if it's going to happen it won't just happen. You'll have to make it happen and it's not going to be easy.

Comment: +1. This is the best answer you're likely to get. Make games, get your foot in the door somewhere using what you've spent years learning to do. Then work on transitioning if you're still set on that path.

Answer (score 3):

Let's talk about my experience. I did a diploma in game design, cool right? Then I did a year of games design at degree level, super cool. And then my dreams kinda ended there. I found getting work in the game industry extremely difficult and I had qualifications that were intended to allow easier access into the industry. I ended up with an apprenticeship in software development, a real turn around.

But I still have this spark of games design and development in me, so I took to making my own game. I made a really bad Flappy Bird clone to start with (to get used to GameMakers engine) then took to Unity and Unreal, and found what I enjoyed to work with (which was 2d games with GameMaker.)

I am now working with a company and making assets for games in GameMaker, as well as working on my own project. It will be slow, but this way you have an income, you can live comfortably but also enjoy what you love to do. Making games is fun, but you don't simply make a game, you craft it, mold it from your creativity.

When I visited Ubisoft in Newcastle, one of the designers told me "Never make a game the people want, make a game you want... people will soon realize it's what they wanted all along."

*To sum it up*

Follow your dream (if it is your dream.) But just be careful, and put your heart into a game you want, and just work on it. If you need help with anything, or a direction to go with creating your first indie game, just ask.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is why I'm wondering if getting a degree in game design after I have my masters degree in informatics will really help me to get into the industry at all. Seems like you need a good portion of luck in order to get a foot in the door.

Comment: You need luck, or to have a successful indie game out at the age of like 12 lol, but yeah people have made big bucks through indie games, then gone on to have a studio. I applied for a few jobs in the game industry but its just extremely hard to get a job, i don't know what you want to do in the industry but indie games and developing yourself as a designer/developer/whatever it is you want, and building your own company as such is the best way. its slow, but if your hearts in it every step is fun and a learning curve.

Comment: Also if it has games in it, avoid it. I would highly recommend a computer science degree over games design/dev, the games degrees are just a fad if im honest.

Comment: Yeah, well, some of my studies are games related like 3D graphics stuff und game engine architechture stuff. The part that's missing is how to design good games. But maybe another 3 years for a game design degree would be a waste of time. What I'm doing right now is just making games and reading a lot about game design. Maybe this will get me far enough.

Comment: All i can recommend is doing what your doing, research games and make assets for games. i.e right i want an fps controller, but instead of using units built in one im going to learn how to make one. Before you know it youl have 30 asset packs and a starting platform for a game.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to trying to do everything myself at least once in order to get a deeper understanding of what's actually going on so I already did basic things like OpenGL programming and writing a basic game engine myself. Same with things like FPS controllers, these things are not that hard and instead of just copy pasting stuff together I like to know how things actually work in detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43729/discussion-between-ryan-white-and-philipp-fromme).

Comment: Is there a reason this was downvoted with no context?